# How to change history on react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

My issue: 
I have nested route between some pages.
 - Navigate page: Page A -> Page B -> Page C, start push Event.
 - When back from from Page C -> Page B with push Event, history save pathName is Page C, so when do a browser back from B, i hope go to page A but go to Page C. do you have any idea for resolve this?

I'm using `react-router-dom` v5